# Unable to remove oil drain screw

Tags: nissan, oil-change

Ok first oil change I've ever done the plug will not come out? I used a bar cheater bar it turns and turns but will not come out. what do i do? I deliver pizza I need this vehicle. Its bad enough I got to weld the frame from rust

Car: 92 Nissan Hardbody D 21

Comment: Are you saying the sump plug just keeps turning?  Was it very tight to start with?   Are you turning it in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1):

That seems like an unlikely scenario. You could try applying pressure against it if you can fit a screwdriver between the pan and plug while loosening.